# Запрет выполнения кода

Tags: php

Как на php запретить выполнение кода на странице, если берется запись из базы и в ней содержится любой код (HTML, PHP, JS...)?
`htmlspecialchars()` не предлагать и функции наподобие.

P.S. Нравится как на этом сайте. Любой код, которые был написан в вопросе вовсе не выполняется.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое: Весь вывод делать через `<pre></pre>`

UPD:

ИМХО: Обычно, делают как-то так ( возможны ошибки ):

```
$rules = Array(
  '[br]' => '<br>',
  '[b]' => '<b>',
  '[/b]' => '</b>'
);

$tag_in = Array();
$tag_out = Array();

foreach ( $rules as $code => $tag ){
  $tag_in[] = $code;
  $tag_out[] = $tag;
}

$res = htmlspecialchars( $res );
$res = str_replace( $tag_in, $tag_out, $res );
```

Comment: Так то да, метод такой работает. Но он больше всего для отладки кода. Тем более, в моем случае не всегда будет выводиться только код, так как это вообщем комментарии к посту, и подразумевается что и будут писать код, который нужно показывать в виде обычного текста.

Comment: htmlspecialchars чем не угодил о @Избранный?

Comment: По теме - хотите чтобы круто работало? Чтобы обрезалось то что ненужно а остальное не обрезалось или что-то в этом духе?

Пишите код а не молитесь на то что кто-то даст вам ответ

Comment: И вообще вы задали практически такой же вопрос [здесь](http://hashcode.ru/questions/70277/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%82-xss), думаете от того что зададите еще раз получите другой ответ?

Comment: htmlspecialchars превращает все в кракозябры, нужно, чтобы отображал код.
Вне не нужен готовый скрип. Нужны лишь советы по поводу этой реализации. Может быть существуют библиотеки, методы и все в этом духе, что помогло бы решить эту задачу.

Comment: Причина тому что все превращается в кракозябры ваша непрофессиональность и бездумность, о таком варианте вы не задумывались? =\

Более откровенно - кракозябры потому-что **вы так написали свой (типа) код**

Comment: @AlexWindHope то не код а говнокод! если элементарно он заключает div в `<center>...</center>` то как выглядит сам php я боюсь увидеть даже в самом страшном сне!)

Comment: Когда я только изучал html, я тоже так делал -.-

Comment: @Дмитрий Алексеевич я конечно понимаю что ошибки делают все, и я их делал тысячи в свое время... но мне правда невлазит в голову как зная PHP и JS(довольно на среднем уровне) не возможно верно составить HTML и CSS? Ведь HTML и CSS это просто школа, нууу вообще ничего сложного, ничего сложно если понимаешь что делаешь. Если не понимаешь что делаешь, не трать время! Золотое ИМХО!

Comment: @timka_s, Ваш код содержит то, что автор не любит :)
htmlspecialchars - >:D

Comment: Автор недекват, я понимю если бы автор не любил потому-что неработало, было бы не всегда применимо и т.д.

Но здесь причина иная - намного проще думать что это УГ функция чем попытаться разобратся в своем (типа) коде

Comment: @AlexWindHope, вскоре у него выйдут все функции УГ, и будет искать замену echo... А, ну ещё может быть исход, в том что, PHP уг, пойду программировать на BF :)

Comment: ОК. задроты, "программисты", юмористы... Походу все гении и задротят с 3 лет. Если же, все туго, то htmlspecialchars(); - нужная функция, но она заменяет теги на HTML сущности, которые отображаются в сообщение. Эти сущности, как раз мне НЕ НУЖНЫ. &lt; - знак тега в лева "<". Нужно его отобразить так, в прежнем отличии HTML, но чтобы сам html,php,js... код не срабатывал при выводе текста с базы на сайте.

Comment: Судя по всему у вас проблема с формулировкой ваших мыслей, либо вы просто неадекват =)

В любом случае объясните "шутам" что вы имеете введу когда пишите:

"Эти сущности, как раз мне НЕ НУЖНЫ. &lt; - знак тега в лева "<". Нужно его отобразить так, в прежнем отличии HTML, но чтобы сам html,php,js... код не срабатывал при выводе текста с базы на сайте"

Лично я не понял абсолютно ничего, по поводу тегов (КаГбЫ) преобразования <, >, ', ", & достаточно для того что-бы ведоносный код не отрабатывал...

Вообщем - предоставьте Ваш код, возможно тода вас кто-то и поймет (хотя это врятли)

Answer (score 2):

Кракозябры  при htmlspecialchars? ох, 100% увидел вместо символов "????????" и думает, дело в htmlspecialchars

Comment: Я об этом "тонко" намекаю второй вопрос =\

Comment: я в шоке, нужно еще сделать для комментов не просто +1 а еще и минус как у ответов!!!

Comment: Юмор не оценил. Кодировка работает полноценно правильно. Но если нечего сказать по поводу реализации метода - просьба засохнуть в теме и не считать себя "умелым программистом-шутником". Жаль, что вам нечего сказать по этому поводу, - А может быть тролем быть куда интереснее, чем реализовывать методы решения проблемы. Мои искренние соболезнования.

Comment: Могу сказать одно. Почему у всех работает, а именно у Вас - нет?
Вам не кажется что у вас проблема в коде? Никто сейчас изобретать велосипед не будет, htmlspecialchars - и всё тут

Answer (score 2):

Сложно открыть исходный код и посмотреть как сделано тут? Кстати тут, любой код который написан в комментарии или вопросе выполняется по типу функции `htmlspecialchars()` и обрамляется в тег `pre`.

Comment: Человеку сложно нормально, вдумчиво, **на русском, с примерами,** прочитать доку о 1ой несчастной функции, а вы тут исходники открыть... Конечно сложно :D

Comment: Я тогда не знаю что и делать. %(